# perl - help troubleshooting dbi statement that uses double and single quotes 

Tags: perl, variables, quotes

I am trying to figure out why I could not get my variables working properly using `Getopt::Std`.

For example in this perl DBI statement where the user and password are enclosed in single quotes, everything works fine:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$dbsrc;host=$node",'foo-bar','mypw');
```

But I want to change this statement so that I can pass in a variable for $user, $pw.
I am using `Getopt::Std;` to pass in these values:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$dbsrc;host=$node", '$user','$pw');
```

THIS WORKS NOW:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$dbsrc;host=$node", $user,$pw);
```

I get the following error mesg:

```
DBI connect('database=;host=hostname','',...) failed:
```

UPDATED: 
After input from everybody, the best way to troubleshoot this for me was to see if my vars were being followed through. I basically was passing in the wrong values. So, simply I tested the dbi piece with getopts for those 2 values and nothing else and was able to get it to work.

Comment: show how you are setting $user and $pw; the double quoted version should work (as should just passing `...=3306", $user, $pw)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't showing all of the error message, but the part you do show seems to have an empty value for the user name. Are you sure your `$user` and `$pw` are actually set up right at that point in your program?

Comment: I am using Getopt to pass in vars. My program was working until I added options to passing in the user and pw. Now I can't get it to read the values if I pass it in outside the program.

Comment: Right. Try setting `$user` and `$pw` explicitly and see if your `DBI->connect()` starts working. Then close this question and create one where you show how you're trying to use Getopt.

Comment: Thanks. I am testing this now and will rewrite this question for clarity. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 4):

The quotes are redundant (`…306", $user, $pw)` would resolve to the same thing), but if the first version works then the problem is the values of the variables and not how you use them.

Comment: Thanks. See my edits. I tried a number of things like '$user' or just $user, but dbi still fails

Comment: Still can't see how you are populating the `$opt` hash.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that when you use double quotes, the variables interpolate in the string, so the final string will be the value you have in your variables. 
With single quotes, the final string will not be interpolated by the variable value, so it will be '$user', no matter the value of $user variable.

Comment: Thanks. See my edits. I tried a number of things like '$user' or just $user, but dbi still fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$dbsrc;host=$node;mysql_compression=1;port=3306", $user,$pw);
```

should work, provided that `$dbsrc`, `$node`, `$user`, and `$pw` are set correctly.  What is the rest of your error message?

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$dbsrc;host=$node;mysql_compression=1;port=3306", '$user','$pw');
```

doesn't work because the single quotes cause the literal strings "$user" and "$pw" to be sent as login credentials rather than the values of the variables `$user` and `$pw`.